# ngrepeat div in PrimeNG

Tags: angular, primeng

```
<div *ngFor="#value in values">
<div *ngIf="selectedItem == values[values.indexOf(value)].data">
<p-picklist [source]="listItems" [target]="targetItems[values.indexOf(value)]">
<template let-label>
        <li class="ui-picklist-item">
            {{label.label}}
        </li>
    </template>
<p-picklist>
```

There is a http post call from ts `ngOnInit()` to initialize values array but I keep getting values `undefined error`, I think the code snippet is correct, may be service call is not completed and `html` is rendered before that is it possible in Angular 2 ?

Comment: where is your div closed ? where is your http post call code ? post your question with full code or some plunker

Comment: Based on this my assumption would be that you are not initializing the array with any value on load. Give the `values` item a value of [] in the component code.

Comment: and one thing more `#` is deprecated in `*ngFor`  use `let` instead

Comment: Please add the code from `ngOnInit()` method also here.